# PHP custom sort preg_match_all?

Tags: php, regex

So I know there are articles out there about custom ordering but I think my situation may be a little different (Or could just be my workaround sucks :P  ).  Here is the quick scenario.

I pull XML data from curl off a report url that we have. (not properly formatted!)  So let's use the following example:  I get the following data back in one long list.

```
<Site>My Sites</Site>
<Customer>PHPSTEVE</Customer>
<Name>Griswald</Name>
<Site> Evil Dead</Site>
<Customer>Bruce</Customer>
<Name>Campbell</Name>
```

I can't use the XML function because the format header is incorrect so I won't get into that.. So instead I use a preg_match_all

```
preg_match_all("/<Site>(.*?)<\/Site>|<Customer>(.*?)<\/Customer>|<Name>(.*?)<\/Name>/is", $resp, $output_array[]);
```

Then I go through and I know this is not good but it works..

```
foreach(array_reverse($output_array[0][0]) as $info){

    $myinfo = $info . $myinfo;

}
```

Everything works as I use a str_replace and just put in my table tags etc.. Obviously I'm doing the reading in reverse.. it's ok I want it that way for this.

```
Site      | Customer | Name
----------+----------+------
Evil Dead | Bruce    | Campbell
```

What if I want "Customer" field first? So basically I'm changing the horizontal order of Site and Customer etc...  Remember there are multiple records all in a line so I am trying to figure out how I would move Customer to where I want it.. or any field for that matter.  Based off of my code above, I don't believe I can accomplish it the way I want to so I'm not sure of another way to do it.

I would like to report it as this:

```
Customer | Site      | Name
---------+-----------+------
Bruce    | Evil Dead | Campbell
```

Any help would be appreciated. NOTE:  I don't care about reading bottom up or top down.. just field changes.   Thanks

UPDATE:  The XMl issue I run into is:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<results>
<Site>My Sites</Site>
<Customer>PHPSTEVE</Customer>
<Name>Griswald</Name>
<Site> Evil Dead</Site>
<Customer>Bruce</Customer>
<Name>Campbell</Name>
</results>
```

Comment: Can you provide the incorrect format header?

Comment: Use `PREG_SET_ORDER` and named match groups. You're currently concatenating the matches including the xml tags; it seems inplausible that you could ever correctly reorder that by itself in any menaningful manner.

Comment: This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
    <results>

That is the error I get.. but the rest is in order.

Comment: I have tried the PREG_SET_ORDER but it appears that it brought all the instances of one tag first and the rest of the data at the end.  So I would get all CUSTOMER's.. then the rest not go through each set and provide "CUSTOMER" as the first field then Name etc..

Comment: Do you not have control over the XML generation?  If so, you should fix that first to have proper hierarchical groupings like `<item><site>...</site><customer>...</customer><name>...</name></item><item>...</item>`

Comment: Something like this would have the name & values: `preg_match_all("#<(?!/)([^>]+)>([^<]*)#", $string, $output_array,PREG_SET_ORDER);`, but it seems just a `<root>$yourstring</root>` would likely make it valid for XML parsing.

Comment: No unfortunately I don't have control over the XML and the program is by far not robust for queries or I could just get the specific data I need such as querying a database... just a bunch of XML data as far as the eye can see.   After reviewing what SoaperGEM gave me.. that wouldn't be enough anyways due to how I need to format etc..  I have already had to use Curl to create dynamic urls that give the reports so it has been a long battle but I made it to the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
function sortCustomerKeys($a, $b)
{
    if ( $a == 'Customer' && $b != 'Customer' ) {
        return 1;
    } else if ( $a != 'Customer' && $b == 'Customer' ) {
        return -1;
    }
    return strnatcasecmp($a, $b);
}

$customers = array();
$advance = array(
    'Customer'    => 0,
    'Name'        => 0,
    'Site'        => 0
);

if ( preg_match_all('@<(Customer|Name|Site)>\\s*(.*?)\\s*</\\1>@is', $resp, $m) ) {

    for ($i = 0, $j = 0; $i < count($m[1]); $i++) {

        $tag = $m[1][$i];
        $value = $m[2][$i];
        $customers[$j][$tag] = $value;

        $advance[$tag] = 1;
        if ( array_sum($advance) == count($advance) ) {
            $advance = array(
                'Customer'    => 0,
                'Name'        => 0,
                'Site'        => 0
            );
            uksort($customers[$j], 'sortCustomerKeys');
            $j++;
        }

    }

}

var_dump($customers);
```

Comment: Thanks.. I'll give that a try.  I know my method basically limits being able to use any ksort or usort.  I appreciate the input and will let you know how I make out.

Comment: One more question..  So if I wanted to change Customer and Name and Site.  If I have another report and I want to just move Customer to the end.. so Name >> Site >> Customer, what exactly do I change to move that order?  Other than that it appears to do what I need it to do.  Thanks!

Comment: You'd have to use a custom sorting function, instead of just the default ksort(). I'll update my answer with one included.

Comment: Ok, I was thinking of uksort.. I looked at some examples but they didn't quite order it how I expected.  I appreciate the update.

Comment: That did the trick.  I don't usually deal with more complex (complex to me) arrays so I thank you for your patience.

Comment: Is there a quick way to foreach that?  I know the regular foreach won't work.

Comment: Sorry..   so the var_dump($customers) has all the data.. but for formatting.. I am making tables etc.. so the following will won't work

    foreach($customers as $key){
      echo $key"\n";
    }

The following only returns one result
   foreach($customers['0'] as $key){
    .. do stuff
   }

Comment: so basically I'm trying to take that $customers[x] and get all the data.. instead of specifying ['0']  or ['1'] etc.. .

Comment: Iterating over the most basic array... that's programming 101 right there, and a separate question from this one. You're going to have to do a nested foreach (i.e. `foreach ( $customers as $customer ) { foreach ( $customer as $key => $val ) { } }`; and quite frankly I can't hold your hand *that* much. You're going to have to figure some of this out yourself.

Comment: I already got it.. jumped the gun on that.. long day but Thanks anyways.